# What changes need to make after changing deployment target in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, podfile

I am working on an iOS project. This project has been implemented in Swift with some pods (Frameworks) included in the project.
Recently a requirement has come to change Deployment Target from iOS 8.0 to 9.0, I changed it and built the app. The app works fine without any error. But this project has Podfile with below line,

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

I am confused whether to change this as well or not.
Other than this please mention any other changes required in the project after changing deployment target?

Comment: yes you need to change that platform so new pod with delopment target will be downloaded

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should change the podfile as well, so that the code in the library also gets compiled with iOS 9 as its deployment target.

Comment: ok, nice, But other than this do I need to bother about anything else even on deployment time. Any configuration updates on my Apple developer account at the time of releasing next version?

Comment: No. Deployment targets are per app, not per developer.